# Google Map API 3 marker's not showing

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map API 3 and google geocoder. The problem is It's not showing the marker and info window I am bringing the data by ajax and calling a function showAddress(elemId, address) Where elementId is div id where the map will be rendered. Here the code for the google map

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var geocoder;
var map;
var lat;
var lng;
function showAddress(elemId, address) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status){
//        console.log(results[0].geometry.location.YA);
            lat = results[0].geometry.location.Ya;
            lng = results[0].geometry.location.Za;
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 15,
                    center:  new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(elemId),
                    mapOptions)
            $('a#full-'+elemId).attr('href','http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q='+lat+','+lng+'')
            var marker 
            marker = "marker_"+elemId;
            myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                id:elemId,
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map
            });
            var infowindow = "infowindow"+elemId;
            infowindow  = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'Hello world'
            });
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    });

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all .Ya and .Za are not documented properties so if you use them as in

```
lat = results[0].geometry.location.Ya;
lng = results[0].geometry.location.Za;
```

that code is likely to break.

secondly, **results[0].geometry.location** is already a **google.maps.LatLng()** object, so there is no need to extract the lat and lng separately and create a new one. You can just use it like:

```
map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    id: elemId,
    map: map,
    position: results[0].geometry.location
})
```

Comment: Also pay attention to the first point in Larry's (geocodezip) reply and check the value of the status returned by the geocoder if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)...., as shown in the examples from the documentation: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Answer (score 2):

1. you aren't checking for success in the call to the geocoder (what is the address?)
2. you are not using the documented interface, these will change with the release:

   ```
       lat = results[0].geometry.location.Ya;
       lng = results[0].geometry.location.Za;
   ```